# issue when uploading multiple images - phonegap

Tags: jquery, file-upload, cordova, file-transfer

Iam doing a phonegap project, here iam uploading multiple images to the server as shown below, and i got `success` status for both image upload, but when iam checking at backend it shows only one image as uploaded (the second one). Please check whether any mistakes in upload code, and help me.

```
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey="uploadfile";
                options.fileName=randomNumber.toString().concat(fileNameSelected);
                options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
                options.chunkedMode = false;

                                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                              // first upload
                                ft.upload(i1,'http://xx.xx.xx/mobapp/api/upload-image', 
                                function (r){ 
                                   console.log("ft.upload one"+JSON.stringify(r));
                                   //  second upload
                                   ft.upload(i2,'http:/xxx.xx.xx/mobapp/api/upload-image',
                                   function(r){console.log("ft.upload two"+JSON.stringify(r));},
                                   function(error){alert("image upload two failed");},options);
                                },function(error)
                                {alert("image upload failed");},options);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check this post to add multiple image on your image tag

[Upload multiple images to the api - phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422073/upload-multiple-images-to-the-api-phonegap/20422225?noredirect=1#comment30587024_20422225)

2) On submit button get image src

On your submit buton add

```
if($('#vImage1').attr('src')){
   /* Image Upload1 Start */
     imagefile = $('#vImage1').attr('src');
     uploadPhoto(imagefile, "vImage1");
  /* Image Upload End */
}
if($('#vImage2').attr('src')){
    /* Image Upload2 Start */
     imagefile = $('#vImage2').attr('src');
     uploadPhoto(imageURI, "vImage2");         
    /* Image Upload End */
 }

 function uploadPhoto(imageURI, vImage) {
  var imagefile = imageURI; 
   /* Image Upload Start */
  var ft = new FileTransfer();                     
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();                      
  options.fileKey= vImage;                      
  options.fileName=imagefile.substr(imagefile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  
  var params = new Object();
  params.value1 = "test";
  params.value2 = "param";                       
  options.params = params;
  options.chunkedMode = false;                       
  ft.upload(imagefile, your_service_url, win, fail, options);   
 }
```

**Processing multiple simultaneous uploads with Cordova**

[Simultaneous uploads with Cordova](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/10/processing-multiple-simultaneous-uploads-with-cordova)

[***More....***](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/multiupload)

Comment: If want to upload ten images then I need to make ten server call? is it right?   . I think this worst method to call ten times for uploading ten images.. Is there possibility to upload ten image in single server call?

Comment: See this blog: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/10/processing-multiple-simultaneous-uploads-with-cordova

Comment: hi,  i have seen the your tutorial, but if wanna upload 10 images, so it makes 10 http call. I want to upload all 10 images in single http call

Comment: I think Cordova still does not provide this kind of functionality , may be in future in possible. If you will found any other solution inform me.

Comment: Ok Sure... Thanks for your response :-)